# RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/packs/application-8e6ca2ce7d44b0980e70.js"

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker, routes

The js code from the application fails while loading cause I made some changes with the NPM and eslint. Any solution for it?
Not going to profile tab (No routing error)

```
import 'core-js/stable';
import 'dom4';
import WebpackerReact from 'webpacker-react';
import Profile from 'containers/Profile';
require('@rails/ujs').start();
WebpackerReact.setup({ Profile });
```

```
Started GET "/packs/application-8e6ca2ce7d44b0980e70.js" for 172.20.0.1 at 2023-01-16 07:01:18 +0000
web_1           |   
web_1           | ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/packs/application-8e6ca2ce7d44b0980e70.js"):
web_1           |   
web_1           | actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:65:in `call'
web_1           | rollbar (2.22.1) lib/rollbar/middleware/rails/show_exceptions.rb:22:in `call_with_rollbar'
web_1           | newrelic_rpm (6.9.0.363) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:99:in `call'
web_1           | actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:33:in `call'
web_1           | newrelic_rpm (6.9.0.363) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:99:in `call'
web_1           | railties (5.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
web_1           | railties (5.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `block in call'
web_1           | activesupport (5.2.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:71:in `block in tagged'
web_1           | activesupport (5.2.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:28:in `tagged'
web_1           | activesupport (5.2.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:71:in `tagged'
web_1           | railties (5.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call'
web_1           | newrelic_rpm (6.9.0.363) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:99:in `call'
web_1           | sprockets-rails (3.2.1) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
web_1           | newrelic_rpm (6.9.0.363) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:99:in `call'
web_1           | actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:81:in `call'
web_1           | newrelic_rpm (6.9.0.363) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:99:in `call'
web_1           | request_store (1.4.1) lib/request_store/middleware.rb:19:in `call'
web_1           | newrelic_rpm (6.9.0.363) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:99:in `call'
web_1           | actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:27:in `call'
web_1           | newrelic_rpm (6.9.0.363) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:99:in `call'
web_1           | rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/method_override.rb:24:in `call'
```

Comment: Please provide more info than this. What environment are you getting this error (ie, prod, dev, test)? Was this working fine before you made the change? What changes did you make?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @stellenberger I was on dev environment and I installed a package eslint so the changes we made in node modules and then onwards the routing error started to come for profile tab